# How to loop AsyncHttpClient B inside AsyncHttpClient A with data list of url from AsyncHttpClient in java Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, loops, android-studio, asynchttpclient

I want to add data to list of user from detailClient(inside client) for every url from client.

onCreate in MainActivity:

```
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.bar_progress);
    etSearch = findViewById(R.id.et_search);
    ibSearch = findViewById(R.id.ib_search);

    RecyclerView rvItem = findViewById(R.id.rv_item);

    adapter = new UserAdapter();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    rvItem.setAdapter(adapter);
    rvItem.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    ibSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String search = etSearch.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(search)) return;
            showLoading(true);
            setSearchUser(search);

        }
    });
```

showLoading in MainActivity:

```
private void showLoading(Boolean state) {
    if (state) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

setSearch code in MainActivity:

```
public void setSearchUser(final String searchName) {

    String url = "https://api.github.com/search/users?q=" + searchName;

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(url, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d("Exception", throwable.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            Log.d(TAG, "client onSuccess");

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                JSONArray items = obj.getJSONArray("items");

                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject itemObj = items.getJSONObject(i);
                    String detailUrl = itemObj.getString("url");

                    getDetail(detailUrl);

                }

                adapter.setData(listItems);
                showLoading(false);

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
            }

        }
    });
}
```

getDetail code in MainActivity:

```
public void getDetail(String url) {
    AsyncHttpClient detailClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
    detailClient.get(url, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d("Exception", throwable.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            Log.d(TAG, "detailClient onSuccess");

            try {
                JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                User user = new User();
                user.setLogin(resObj.getString("login"));
                user.setAvatarUrl(resObj.getString("avatar_url"));
                user.setFollowersUrl(resObj.getString("followers_url"));
                user.setFollowingUrl(resObj.getString("following_url"));
                user.setName(resObj.getString("name"));
                user.setBlog(resObj.getString("blog"));
                user.setCompany(resObj.getString("company"));
                user.setRepos(resObj.getInt("public_repos"));
                user.setGists(resObj.getInt("public_gists"));
                user.setFollowersNum(resObj.getInt("followers"));
                user.setFollowingNum(resObj.getInt("following"));

                Log.d("Detail Name", user.getName());

                listItems.add(user);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

setData in UserAdapter:

```
public void setData(ArrayList<User> items) {
Log.d(TAG, "setData: called.");
mData.clear();
mData.addAll(items);
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

when imageButton ibSearch is clicked first time nothing change,  second, onBindViewHolder in UserAdapter called. The third time the view is stacked with the before view.

I think the problem is because listItem inside the AsyncHttpClient is not the same with listItem outside the AsyncHttpClient. So how to make listItem inside the AsyncHttpClient same with outside listItem and get data from the looping asynchttpclient?